# VACUUM FULL using another disk

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, maintenance, vacuum, database-size

Current database takes almost all of SSD free space ~802GB. 800 GB of memory is taken by single table and it was never vacuumed since 2019. Recently i deleted old rows from the table and now i need to run VACUUM FULL to reclaim disk space back to OS. The problem is that there is no space left on SSD.
I can connect external SSD (840 GB) but i don't know how to run VACUUM FULL and make it use external disk space.

postgesql 9.5
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with `VACUUM (FULL)`, but you can use `pg_dump` to export the table to the second disk, drop the table and restore the dump.

If that is not feasible, for example because of foreign key constraints, you could

1. create a tablespace on the second disk
2. use `ALTER TABLE` to move the table to that tablespace
3. run `VACUUM (FULL)` on the table
4. move the table back with `ALTER TABLE`
5. remove the tablespace

But this is more cumbersome.

Comment: as far as i know, vacuum FULL using the same disk where table is stored. So i guess there is no point to change tablespace, cause both disks are only slightly bigger than the table.
Also can't DROP table due to foreign key constraints.

Comment: If you have *no resources at all*, life is difficult. Then you'll have to drop and re-create the foreign keys on top of dump/restore.